# Whitelabel error page on localhost:8080\sendMesssage?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, twilio

I have just started Springboot with Twilio but for some reason when I run the localhost\sendMessage command I get the Whitelabel error Page. When I run the below code the test concludes successfully:

```
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping


@RestController
public class SMSController{
    @RequestMapping( "/")
    fun helloSpringBoot() = "Hello Spring Boot!"

}
```

This is the result of the code above:

[image]

But when I run the below code with the localhost:8080\sendMessage I get the screenshot that follows the code:

```
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber


@RestController
public class SMSController{
    @RequestMapping("/sendMessage")
    fun sendMessage(){

        val client = TwilioRestClient.Builder(
                System.getenv("ACCOUNT_SID"),
               System.getenv("AUTH_TOKEN")).build()

        val message = MessageCreator(
                PhoneNumber(System.getenv("+1..........")),
                PhoneNumber("+1.........."),
                "Lambda is annoying..Sigh"
        ).create(client)

    }

}
```

[image]

Am I missing something?

I have added my Stack TRace:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=25281:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\IdeaProjects\demo\out\production\classes;C:\Users\Jevon\IdeaProjects\demo\out\production\resources;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.twilio.sdk\twilio\7.17.9\8de7649313c8fa3dfcbd215b6c0300ca1c4184f5\twilio-7.17.9.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.1.4.RELEASE\a4659d55f57421a5ef122cb670b7b544ef8190e8\spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.1.4.RELEASE\247d7c2efae986f310a29e9fef7174adc91d0835\spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter\2.1.4.RELEASE\8fa436ef4e273cb476d5dc3aa73701a8837460af\spring-boot-starter-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.3.21\d0d5ff2ac2ebd8a42697af41e20fc225a23c5d3b\kotlin-reflect-1.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.3.21\d0634d54452abc421db494ad32dd215e6591c49f\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.guava\guava\18.0\cce0823396aa693798f8882e64213b1772032b09\guava-18.0.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\joda-time\joda-time\2.10.1\9ac3dbf89dbf2ee385185dd0cd3064fe789efee0\joda-time-2.10.1.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.jsonwebtoken\jjwt\0.4\61ce246d937a0fd3acf06d3bef5fc9e3933ae812\jjwt-0.4.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.8\c27c9d6f15435dc2b6947112027b418b0eef32b9\httpclient-4.5.8.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.11\de748cf874e4e193b42eceea9fe5574fabb9d4df\httpcore-4.4.11.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.8\bcd02aa9195390e23747ed40bf76be869ad3a2fb\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.8\28ad1bced632ba338e51c825a652f6e11a8e6eac\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.8\c4eef0e6e20d60fb27af4bc4770dba7bcc3f6de6\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.9.8\11283f21cc480aa86c4df7a0a3243ec508372ed2\jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.9.8\f5a654e4675769c716e5b387830d19b501ca191\jackson-core-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\7c10d545325e3a6e72e06381afe469fd40eb701\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.xml.bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\8531ad5ac454cc2deb9d4d32c40c4d7451939b5d\jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.1.4.RELEASE\3b0c04450d86fc29c9fdad555b4555e553a4008\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hibernate.validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.16.Final\ad9557c558972093c0567a2a1f224f318c00f650\hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-webmvc\5.1.6.RELEASE\cf4ea53740c93e0b8ff951ef0a3eaf154c74dbd0\spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-web\5.1.6.RELEASE\4e15a24feba0581a02efd508af03a15b05570bd4\spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.1.4.RELEASE\d5f8b3f7835a23b4dfd8d1489d265c1e426e317b\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.1.4.RELEASE\5ad0355a8c810b32b9221b9b92746b51c983337f\spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.1.4.RELEASE\2fb669a89cd65b275be20ab755c3742399395dff\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\934c04d3cfef185a8008e7bf34331b79730a9d43\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-context\5.1.6.RELEASE\7b9e80ab68ee91ca0462a0eb2c58a9d957788b\spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-aop\5.1.6.RELEASE\a473d4bca7295f2b90522594e413f9e19107c1d2\spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-beans\5.1.6.RELEASE\90d2f4bf7eced108de0b5bf617abb2b13a6206a3\spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-expression\5.1.6.RELEASE\50fe4080029e43e7612e50fb4d7c7c43e95bf03c\spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-core\5.1.6.RELEASE\9329591e728ef9844911e082e399f4fc3e3ecb37\spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.3.21\d207ce2c9bcf17dc8e51bab4dbfdac4d013e7138\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.3.21\4bcc2012b84840e19e1e28074284cac908be0295\kotlin-stdlib-1.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\7c4f3c474fb2c041d8028740440937705ebb473a\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\6d37bf7b046c0ce2669f26b99365a2cfa45c4c18\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.yaml\snakeyaml\1.23\ec62d74fe50689c28c0ff5b35d3aebcaa8b5be68\snakeyaml-1.23.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.26\8031352b2bb0a49e67818bf04c027aa92e645d5c\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\77100a62c2e6f04b53977b9f541044d7d722693d\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.11\3acb4705652e16236558f0f4f2192cc33c3bd189\commons-codec-1.11.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.activation\javax.activation-api\1.2.0\85262acf3ca9816f9537ca47d5adeabaead7cb16\javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.17\a786505cc2697f7f2d8693c0c318270cc8addd92\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.17.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.17\aacb92c34eb2e88f38a060c9fcaaae329a79c9ca\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.17.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.tomcat.embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.17\595fbb87426e23f27c71b267f22b6e7d2a91a2aa\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.17.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\cb855558e6271b1b32e716d24cb85c7f583ce09e\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jboss.logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\3789d00e859632e6c6206adc0c71625559e6e3b0\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml\classmate\1.4.0\291658ac2ce2476256c7115943652c0accb5c857\classmate-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework\spring-jcl\5.1.6.RELEASE\a4ad3c98c7cc31357e94e12772c8e6449522bc5\spring-jcl-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.3.21\f30e4a9897913e53d778f564110bafa1fef46643\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.21.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.2.3\864344400c3d4d92dfeb0a305dc87d953677c03c\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Jevon\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.logging.log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\f5e9a2ffca496057d6891a3de65128efc636e26e\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar" com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

2019-04-04 15:32:35.584  INFO 8012 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt       : Starting DemoApplicationKt on Javy26 with PID 8012 (C:\Users\Jevon\IdeaProjects\demo\out\production\classes started by Jevon in C:\Users\Jevon\IdeaProjects\demo)
2019-04-04 15:32:35.596  INFO 8012 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-04-04 15:32:35.828  WARN 8012 --- [kground-preinit] o.s.h.c.j.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder    : For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2019-04-04 15:32:39.918  INFO 8012 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-04-04 15:32:39.970  INFO 8012 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-04-04 15:32:39.970  INFO 8012 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
2019-04-04 15:32:40.214  INFO 8012 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-04-04 15:32:40.214  INFO 8012 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4486 ms
2019-04-04 15:32:41.275  INFO 8012 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-04-04 15:32:41.807  INFO 8012 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-04-04 15:32:41.811  INFO 8012 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplicationKt       : Started DemoApplicationKt in 7.81 seconds (JVM running for 10.279)
2019-04-04 15:33:24.230  INFO 8012 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-04-04 15:33:24.230  INFO 8012 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-04-04 15:33:24.250  INFO 8012 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 20 ms
```

Comment: I assume you're actually hitting `localhost:8080/sendMessage` (note the forward slash). Can you provide any stack-trace from the console, your error is most likely in there.

Comment: @matthew.kempson Stack Trace has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went back through the Kotlin documentation rather than focus on the tutorial and made the necessary changes. Once that was done the code started working as it should. See changes below:

```
@RestController
public class SMSController{

    @RequestMapping(value = ["/sendMessage"])
    fun sendMessage(){

        val client = TwilioRestClient.Builder("ACCOUNT_SID",
              "AUTH_TOKEN").build()

        val message = MessageCreator(
                PhoneNumber("+1........"),
                PhoneNumber("+1........"),
                "Lambda is annoying..Sigh").create(client)

    }
}
```